# Product Prices of configurable products

Tags: magento2, configurable-product, price

I am getting stuck with the prices of configurable products on magento 2

I have made a configurable product with 6 simple products in it. Alle the simple products have received their own price. But when I select the product in my webshop the product dont show the right prices. The first product shows the good price, but the others just show the price difference.

In the shopping cart the prices are right.

See pictures below. It is not in English but in Dutch, but probably understandable.

Anyone who knows how to solve this? Am I missing a setting? Thanks in advance.

All settings in the configurable product, with the right prices:
[image: Here you see all the prices are set up right]

first product is selected as standard, with the right price:
[image: first product is selected as standard, with the right price]

when I select the second product, the price will shown the difference instead of the new price:
[image: when I select the second product, the price will shown the difference instead of the new price]

In the shopping cart it shows the right prices:
[image: In the shopping cart it shows the right prices]